# ng-select2 dropdown still shows after clicking browser back button

Tags: jquery, angular

I am using an ng-select2 component here

```html
  <ng-select2 id="supportTicketFilter" class="support-ticket-filter" width="370" [data]="filterValues"
            [options]="options" (valueChanged)="filterTable($event)" name="searchBar" data-selected="selected">
</ng-select2>
```

The issue is that when the drop down is selected as seen below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3lsH.png)

and you click the back button on the browser, the dropdown menu still appears on the next page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtyTM.png)

Has anyone run into this issue before?
The only thing I can think of now is to listen for the back button on the browser and then try to toggle something in the ng-select2.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the app. You can either use another library, or build a custom wrapper around this which listens for route changes in the router

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, there was a class added on the container for the list that is rendered when clicking the dropdown.

for angular solutions was this

```js
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    const selectOptionsContainer = $('.select2-container');
    selectOptionsContainer.removeClass('select2-container--open')
  }
```